# Plural or singular? (target is or are)

Tags: grammar

Should I say that the (a) main target of a project is children or that (b) the main targets are children?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's the subject, not the object, that determines the verb. If your turned the sentence around and made **children** the subject, you would use the plural: **Children are the main target of a project**.

Answer (score 1):

The word `target` has several meanings. In your case, `target` is singular [a person or a particular group of people that something is directed at, or that something is intended for]. The possible variant is `The target audience for a project is children.`

Follow this link to learn more https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/target.